# If a and b are non-negative real numbers then demonstrate inequality

Tags: inequality

If $a$ and $b$ are non-negative real numbers then show that
$$(3a +\frac{4}{a+1}+\frac{8}{\sqrt{2(1+b^2)}})\cdot(3b +\frac{4}{b+1}+\frac{8}{\sqrt{2(1+a^2)}})\geq81.$$
Inequality is less common. To demonstrate the usual instruments (means inequality, ...) did not help. Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: What have you tried? Consider trying to calculate it's minimal values as a function of tow variables

Comment: No derivatives...

Comment: What does that mean? You don't know how? You aren't allowed? You haven't tried?

Comment: from where did you get this?

Comment: @medicu for you. Let $a$ and $b$ be non-negatives. Prove that: $\left(3a+\frac{8}{a+1}+\frac{4}{\sqrt[3]{4(b^3+1)}}\right)\left(3b+\frac{8}{b+1}+\frac{4}{\sqrt[3]{4(a^3+1)}}\right)\geq81$

Comment: Since the LHS is $f(a)\cdot f(b)$, where $f(x)=3x+\frac{4}{x+1}+\frac{8}{\sqrt{2(1+x^2)}} $, I would think the easiest way is to find that $x=1$ is the only positive root of $f'(x)$ and verify $f(1)=9$. Indeed @MichaelRozenberg's inequality is a bit more interesting.

Comment: @Vincenzo Oliva Read please better my problem. Thank you!

Comment: @MichealRozenberg: Of course what I said applies to the OP's inequality, not yours. That's why it is a bit more interesting. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well... Notice that by the AM-GM inequality: 
$$ 3a+\frac{4}{a+1}=\left(a+1\right)+\frac{2\left(a^2+1\right)}{a+1}+1 \ge 2\sqrt{2\left(1+a^2\right)}+1 $$
Then using the Cauchy–Bunyakovsky–Schwarz inequality, we get 
$$ LHS \ge \left(2\sqrt{2\left(1+a^2\right)}+1+\frac{8}{\sqrt{2\left(1+b^2\right)}}\right)\left(\frac{8}{\sqrt{2\left(1+a^2\right)}}+1+2\sqrt{2\left(1+b^2\right)}\right) \ge 81 $$
as desired. The equality occurs when $a=b=1$.

Comment: Great solution! In the first line, you probably meant to say $3a + \frac{4}{a+1} = (a+1)+\frac{2(a^2+1)}{a+1}+1$, and in the second line you are missing a $2$ under some of the radicals.

Comment: Ooooops.. thanks a lot :P