# a hard inequality in 2 variables

Tags: inequality

How can we prove the following inequality

$$\left (3x+\frac{4}{x+1}+\frac{8}{\sqrt{2(y^2+1)}}\right )\left (3y+\frac{4}{y+1}+\frac{8}{\sqrt{2(x^2+1)}}\right )\geq 81,\ \forall x,y\geq 0$$

?

I have proved that: $3x+\frac{4}{x+1}+\frac{8}{\sqrt{2(x^2+1)}}\geq 9, \forall x\geq 0$, with equality only when $x=1$.

Comment: Are you sure about your equations? You have $x$ in your proved equation below the square root, but your original equation reads $y$ there.

Comment: You proved that the arithmetic mean of (3x + 4/(x+1)) and 8/(...) is at least 9/2.   If you prove that their geometric mean is at least 9/2, it solves the problem.

Comment: Continuation of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1682088/weird-inequality-that-seems-to-be-true ?

Comment: The LHS is a symmetric function wrt $x$ and $y$, hence we just need to prove that the minima of the LHS occur along the $x=y$ line.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio  That's a fallacy. For a counter eg check his linked older post.

Comment: @Macavity: what fallacy? I am just saying that it is enough to study the behaviour of that function along the lines $x+y=k$, but obviously a symmetric function may have absolute minima at $(x_0,y_0)$ and $(y_0,x_0)$ with $x_0\neq y_0$. I do not know if it is the case for our symmetric function.

Comment: See here:
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1596353/